# Windows Phone 8.1 throws a FileLoadException on startup

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm currently building a Windows Phone 8.1 App (WinRT). I can build it in Debug Mode in Visual Studio 2013 without any problems. It is also runs in the emulator and on a real device. But when I build the app in Release mode it crashes instantly on both the emulator and the device.

In the Debug Output windows of Visual Studio I can see that a FileLoadException is thrown on startup. This means:

> The exception that is thrown when a managed assembly is found but
>   cannot be loaded.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.fileloadexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Unfortunately I can not see which assembly causes the problem! Is there any means to make the information visible?

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in MarketIQ.exe
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
'MarketIQ.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\en-US\mscorlib.debug.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
'MarketIQ.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\Data\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppxLayouts\c53a5ef4-9f4f-4a1d-a5f4-2e73b5806daeVS.Release_AnyCPU.oprins\Log.Model.Client.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The program '[3020] MarketIQ.exe' has exited with code -1073741189 (0xc000027b).
```

Comment: It's likely that if you delete the bin\debug folder, you'll have the same error with debug builds. Check the references of your project, when one cannot be found, Visual Studio corrects it automatically by referencing the dll in your output folder, leading to the kind of symptoms you're describing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was device dependent. The app now runs smoothly after a factory reset.